# Bitnami says 'no enough permissions to bind to the port...'

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am installing wordpress of Bitnami in ubuntu 12.04 amd64.
When I run installation, it pops a window letting me choose 'MySQL Server port'.
I use the default 3306.
But it says : `It seems you do not have enough permissions to bind to the port or the port is already taken by another application. Please select another one.`
I use 'service mysql status' and 'sudo lsof -i:3306' to find that mysql service is running with port 3306.
What is the matter?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like Bitnami is trying to bind its own MySQL or DB server or something to 3306.  Choose a different port, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BitNami installers are self-contained and independent of your system. The BitNami WordPress stack will install MySQL and Apache servers in your installation directory. If you already have a MySQL server running, you can configure the installer to use a different port, for example 3307.

I hope it helps.